# Creating an index without typing the integers: Python

Tags: python, indexing

So I normally create indexes by typing `index = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`
I have a DF that has 5,000 + entries, so I'm obviously not trying to do this manually. How would I create an index on all of the columns without typing it in using the method above?
I'll put my starting code in just for a reference

```
url = 'http://www.esapubs.org/archive/ecol/E084/094/MOMv3.3.txt'
read = pd.read_csv(url, delimiter = '\t', names = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'])

df_ex = pd.DataFrame(read)
```

Comment: Using `range()`? For your 5000+ `range(1,5001)`

Comment: So, what do you expect to be the column names? By the way, `read` is already a DataFrame.

Comment: What do you want your index to do? Does it signify something meaningful about the columns or rows in your data?

Answer (score 1):

```
index = range(1, 11)
>>> index
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your *names* parameter is one less than the actual columns, so the first column is treated as index; if you want a range index, specify the `header` to be None, since the actual data doesn't contain a header, or add one letter to your names parameter so that it matches the number of columns, `read_csv` will create a range index for you automatically:

```
url = 'http://www.esapubs.org/archive/ecol/E084/094/MOMv3.3.txt'
read = pd.read_csv(url, delimiter="\t", header=None)

read.head()
```

[image]

---

Or:

```
read = pd.read_csv(url, delimiter = '\t', names = list("abcdefghi"))

read.head()
```

[image]